# Calling of .NET Function Taking inputs as objects from Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

This is strange for me. I was able to set up the environment so that I can call .NET method (via COM) from a classic ASP page.

Everything actually works as intended until when I have to call a .NET method that requires a .NET type.

So I have a method named

I have a function like this in .Net

```
Public Sub SetTable(ByVal _City As City, ByVal _Country As Country)
          'doing some thing
End Sub
```

and i have asp code like this:

```
dim CountryUtil, City, Country
set CountryUtil= Server.CreateObject("mydll.CountryUtil")
set city = Server.CreateObject("mydll.City")
set Country = Server.CreateObject("mydll.Country")
city.id= 123
city.property = "so and so"

Country.id= 123
Country.property = "so and so"

categoryUtil.SetTable(City, Country)
```

' I get this error here:

'Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0005' 
'Invalid procedure call or argument: 'SetTable'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what version of the .NET framework you're working with?

Comment: `categoryUtil` is not declared anywhere. Maybe you mean `CountryUtil.SetTable(City, Country)`?

Comment: yes Shadow Wizard it is CountryUtil not categoryUtil. I am using VS2008(frame work 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

if `countryUtil` is a class, you might have to initiate a new instance of it first.
Also, instead of `Set`ting, you can just create new variables. Don't forget case sensitivity. If you try to pass the City instead of the city, it will give you problems.

```
''# Create a new instance of the categoryUtil Class
Dim countryUtil As New mydll.CountryUtil 

Dim city As New mydll.City
Dim country As New mydll.Country

city.id= 123
city.property = "so and so"

country.id= 123
country.property = "so and so"

''# Instead of using the Class directly, you use the new instance of the Class
''# and pass the lowercase variables instead of the UpperCase Classes.
countryUtil.SetTable(city, country)
```

---

#### EDIT

If you were using a later version of the .NET framework, you could shorten it like this

```
''# Create a new instance of the categoryUtil Class
Dim countryUtil As New mydll.CountryUtil 

Dim city As New mydll.City With {.id = 123, .property="so and so"}
Dim country As New mydll.Country With {.id=123, .property="so and so"}


''# Instead of using the Class directly, you use the new instance of the Class
''# and pass the lowercase variables instead of the UpperCase Classes.
countryUtil.SetTable(city, country)
```

---

#### EDIT

Check out this link to see how to mix asp and asp.net
http://knol.google.com/k/from-classic-asp-to-asp-net-and-back#

Answer (score 0):

ASP values you set as values for the params are `VARIANT`.
But you defined different variable types in your function.

Example:

.NET Code:

```
Public Sub Test(param as String)
```

Classic ASP:

```
Dim yourParam : yourParam = "Testvalue"
YourClass.Test(yourParam)
```

This will fail.

Classic ASP:

```
Dim yourParam : yourParam = "Testvalue"
YourClass.Test(CStr(yourParam))
```

This will work.

So as resolution you need to take care to set the correct variable types while you call your function! In classic ASP everything is `VARIANT`.
Sidenote: Dictionary Objects, Array's are tricky to handle, I managed to define in .NET my variables as `object[]` and convert them inside the class.